# No SYSVOL\NETLOGON on 2012 STD DC Server

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, replication, dfs-r

I have 2 2012 servers.
I found out there's no share of neither SYSVOL nor NETLOGON on the BDC.

I'm getting many 5002:

```
The DFS Replication service encountered an error communicating with partner QA-DC for replication group Domain System Volume.
```

and 4614:

```
The DFS replication service initilizaed SYSVOL at local path c:\windows\sysvol\domain and is waiting to perform initial replication
```

I already tried non-authoritive restore on the BDC and authoritive restore on the PDC according to this guide:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2218556

I'm afraid that didnt help.

Edit:

I found something strange...
Looking at the debug log it looks like dev-dc which is my secondary DC, does not even try to communicate with QA-DC which is the PDC. The logs do show this problematic(?) line:

> "Cluster Service is not installed or configured. Skipping VCO
>   Polling".

One more thing I found out is when looking at "DFS Management" snapping I discovered that QA-DC's membership in the "Domain System Volume" is somehow disabled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending hours on top of hours this is the only thing that eventually worked:

http://jorgequestforknowledge.wordpress.com/2010/page/4/

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicate a general connectivity issue between your second Domain Controller (stop calling it BDC) and `QA-DC`, that causes initial replication of SYSVOL to fail. As such, the restore operation doesn't really make sense.

The DFS-R service requires tcp traffic on the following destination ports to be allowed in any firewall between the two:

```
RPC Endpoint Mapper    tcp/135
Dynamic port range*    tcp/49152-65535
```

In addition, you need to make sure that the second DC can resolve QA-DC in DNS.

If these requirements have already been met, inspect the DFSR debug logs. Post any relevant failure details if it doesn't make sense to you. By default, these are located at `%windir%\debug\` and will have names like "Dfsr00001.log".

---

* *[These](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929851) are also commonly referred to as **Ephemeral Ports** or **Dynamically Allocated High Ports***

Comment: Where do u want the logs from? qa-dc or the pdc?
there's no firewall between the 2. Win firewall has also been turned off.

Comment: From the failing DC

Comment: I'm gonna update on a new post.